# Flutter Sqflite How to Get Related Data as JSON Objects

Tags: sql, json, database, flutter, sqflite

I'm using **Sqflite** for local storage in my **Flutter** application. I have two tables in my database.

Here are my tables:

```
task_table

id
name

subtask_table

id
name
task_id
```

Each task can have multiple subtasks related to them.

My question is how can I read task data with their subtasks as a JSON format in Sqflite?

Here is my desired result:

```
{
 id: 1,
 name: "Task 1",
 subtasks: [
   {
     id: 1,
     name: "Subtask 1",
    },
    {
     id: 2,
     name: "Subtask 2",
    },
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner join for the tables and get the data,

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> dbList = await db.rawQuery('SELECT task_table.id, task_table.name, subtask_table.id , subtask_table.name , subtask_table.task_id FROM task_table INNER JOIN subtask_table ON task_table.id = subtask_table.task_id');
```

but it will not be in the format you want.

If you need the data in that kind of format then you need to fetch data from both the tables and make data in your desired format like below:

```
Future<List<TaskAndCorrespondingSubTasks>> getAllBasketsWithCorresponding() async {
  Database db = await openDatabase('your_db_name.db');
  try {
  List<TaskAndCorrespondingSubTasks> taskList = [];
  // fetch tasks;

  List<Subtasks> subTaskList = [];
  //fetch subtasks;

  List<TaskAndCorrespondingSubTasks> data = [];
  taskList.forEach((element) {
    data.add(TaskAndCorrespondingSubTasks(
        name: element.name,
        id: element.id,
        subtasks:
            subTaskList.where((ele) => ele.taskId == element.id).toList()));
    });

  return data;
  } on Exception {
    return [];
  } finally {
    await db.close();
  } 
}
```

And make a data model with your desired data from the json you have provided.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you mean I should fetch data from the tables separately and then add them to my object list?

Comment: Yes, Other than that you can't get data in your desired format